# Display someone's events when using Many to Many

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application which keeps tracks of Volunteers and what events they are signed up to.

A Volunteer can have many events and an event can have many Volunteers.

I want to have it so:

- A Volunteer can view their events that they are signed up to (Doing this through my DB) in a List - essentially just the details of the event specific to if they are signed up for.
- And also sign up for new events - press a link which takes their ID and adds it to the Event/Appointment list thats in the Event/Appointment table to update the event and the many to many table.

I'm trying to create a method to do these but I'm lost. I've tried to use a multi select list with javascript but its not looking well.

Here is my Volunteer Entity along with what I have so far:

```
public class Volunteer
{
    [Key]
    public int VolunteerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool GardaVetted { get; set; }

    public string VolunteerRole { get; set; }

    public string VolunteerPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Church")]
    public int ChurchId { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key
    public virtual Church Church { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Appointments> Appointments { get; set; }

    public Volunteer()
    {
        this.Appointments = new HashSet<Appointments>();
    }

}
```

Volunteer Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AvailableCeremonies()
    {
        var ceremonies = (from a in db.Appointments
                          where a.Fee != null && a.Slots != 0
                          select a).ToList();

        return View(ceremonies);
    }

    public ActionResult VolunteerCeremonies(Appointments apps)
    {
        string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

        var getVolunteer = (from vol in db.Volunteers
                            where username == vol.Username
                            select vol).SingleOrDefault();


        //List of Volunteers in the Ceremonies
        apps.Volunteers = new List<Volunteer>();




        db.SaveChanges();

        return View(apps);

    }
```

My Events/Appointments entity because I don't need to do anything in the other controller:

```
public class Appointments
{
    [Key]
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }

    public string DetailsOfAppointment { get; set; }

    public int? Fee { get; set; }

    public string RoomType { get; set; }

    public string NameOfApplicant { get; set; }

    public string ApplicantPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string ApplicantEmail { get; set; }

    public int Slots { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime DateOfAppointment { get; set; }

    public string ThemeColour { get; set; }

    public Boolean Confirmed { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Admins")]
    public int AdministrationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Church")]
    public int ChurchId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("Volunteers")]
    //public int VolunteerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Church Church { get; set; }

    public virtual Administration Admins { get; set; }

    public ICollection <Volunteer> Volunteers { get; set; }

    public Appointments()
    {
        this.Volunteers = new HashSet<Volunteer>();
    }
}
```

}

Is there anyway of doing these or even point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? A method to display it to the user? How to obtain it from the database? How to organize it in code? How to represent it visually?

Comment: I'll edit my question, tired eyes from coding all day lol

Comment: @RonBeyer just edited there

Comment: On action VolunteerCeremonies, do you wanna list all appointments from a user? if so you should use

var ceremonies = (from a in getVolunteer.Appointments
                          where a.Fee != null && a.Slots != 0
                          select a).ToList();

        return View(ceremonies);

Comment: To add a new appointment to this user

getVolunteer.Appointments.Add(apps);
db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @MiltonFilho yes, I would like a user to their specific users events.